# OSI model, clarification about the role of SAP

Tags: osi, architecture

I'm studying the OSI architecture model and I have doubts about the role of the SAP (Service Access Point). From what I'm getting it's an interface between the (N+1)-PDU and the (N)-SDU but does it also offer some sort of "virtual" connection between the same layers of two systems?
Can you clarify this aspect?

Comment: Have a look at a different architecture called the [Internet Protocol Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).  Less layers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each layer adds header during "send" operation. The corresponding layer in the destination (or next hop) reads the contents of that header during "receive" operation. We can see this as a virtual connection between layers of those two hosts.

Here is an image from Wikipedia illustrating this concept: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:OSI-model-Communication.svg